# Problem with Array list in java (always take the last element into the array)

Tags: java

I have a problem with array list

```
public void loadFiles(String folder, List<MyFile> listFiles) {
       MyFile myfile = new MyFile();
        File directory = new File(folder);
        //get all the files from a directory
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                loadFiles(file.toString());
            }
            if (file.isFile()) {
                //set name and size to myfile
                myfile.setName(file.getName());
                myfile.setSize(file.length());
                listFiles.add(myfile);
            }
        }
    }
```

On folder (Myfolder) have 3 file (TC1,TC2,TC3).
but in listFiles output (TC1,TC1,TC1)
what is going on explain me.
And How to fix this issue

thanks

Comment: You are always adding `myFile` to the `List`.

Comment: I agree with Zephyr, change `myfile` under `if (file.isFile())` to file

Comment: create a new instance like  `MyFile myfile = new MyFile(); ` inside the for loop and then add it to the `listFiles`. Currently you are just adding the same object multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Raj 
"create a new instance like MyFile myfile = new MyFile(); inside the for loop and then add it to the listFiles. Currently you are just adding the same object multiple times." – Raj 1 min ago

```
public void loadFiles(String folder, List<MyFile> listFiles) {
        File directory = new File(folder);
        //get all the files from a directory
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList) {
            **MyFile myfile = new MyFile();**
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                loadFiles(file.toString());
            }
            if (file.isFile()) {
                //set name and size to myfile
                myfile.setName(file.getName());
                myfile.setSize(file.length());
                listFiles.add(myfile);
            }
        }
    }
```

It work .
Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same object to the `List` each time you loop through the files. You need to create a new file to add, not just change the name of `myFile` each time:

```
if (file.isFile()) {
    //set name and size to NEW MyFile
    MyFile newFile = new MyFile();
    newFile .setName(file.getName());
    newFile .setSize(file.length());
    listFiles.add(newFile );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you want to get three different file instances in your list, but you create only one - you execute a new MyFile() only once in your code.

So you get three references to the same object. And whenever you change properties of that instance via `myfile.setName(file.getName());` and `myfile.setSize(file.length());`, you see the change in all places where you reference this instance, so you get the same results in all three places of your list.

Instead of

```
            myfile.setName(file.getName());
            myfile.setSize(file.length());
```

you should do something like

```
            myfile = new MyFile(file.getName(), file.length());
```

inside your loop.